# Error compiling "fortune" on x86_64

Tags: macos, compilation, makefile, symbols

I'm on an x86_64 machine. I'm trying to build `fortune` using its makefile, but I get an error about missing symbols:

```
cd fortune && make CC='gcc' \
                    CFLAGS='-O2 -DFORTDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes\"" -DOFFDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DHAVE_REGEX_H -DBSD_REGEX -I../util'   \
                    LDFLAGS='-s' LIBS=''
gcc -s -o fortune fortune.o 
ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_re_comp", referenced from:
      _getargs in fortune.o
  "_re_exec", referenced from:
      _matches_in_list in fortune.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [fortune] Error 1
make: *** [fortune-bin] Error 2
```

I get the same error if I try to build for an x86 host:

```
terences-imac:fortune-mod-9708 MAU$ make host=x86
cd fortune && make CC='gcc' \
                    CFLAGS='-O2 -DFORTDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes\"" -DOFFDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DHAVE_REGEX_H -DBSD_REGEX -I../util'   \
                    LDFLAGS='-s' LIBS=''
gcc -s -o fortune fortune.o 
ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_re_comp", referenced from:
      _getargs in fortune.o
  "_re_exec", referenced from:
      _matches_in_list in fortune.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [fortune] Error 1
make: *** [fortune-bin] Error 2`
```

Comment: Compile what? What is "it"? An Operating system? An app? What device are you compiling on? Your question is very vague.

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Comment: I realize this wasn't the greatest question, but it does say "fortune" on practically every line

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your are trying to compile on Mac OS X, going by the tag "osx" and the hostname "terences-imac" ...

As far as I know, the original fortune (ftp://metalab.unc.edu/pub/Linux/games/amusements/fortune/) is only intended for Linux.

There are some BSD Ports, you could check : https://github.com/ArrantSquid/Fortune-OSX  which is working for me on OSX 10.9 (clang and all)

Comment: I kind of guessed that. But then the makefile mentioned BSD regex and I assumed if it worked on other *BSDs it would work on mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is why, when people complain about autotools, you should ignore them.  Remember that autotools are for the *users*, not for *maintainers*.

You don't specify what operating system you're building on.  However, the missing symbols are related to regular expression parsing and in your makefile you're setting `-DBSD_REGEX`.  If you're not on a BSD system that might be part of the problem.

If you're using GNU/Linux, then looking at the `re_comp` man page, I see it recommends:

```
#define _REGEX_RE_COMP
```

so you  might try adding `-D_REGEX_RE_COMP` to your compile line.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me, WRT your question.

Comment: It's clear you're using BSD regex by your errors; that's not the missing information.  The question is, are you compiling on a BSD system?  Or on some other kind of system like GNU/Linux?  Did you try adding the `-D_REGEX_RE_COMP` flag as I suggested?  Did it work?

Comment: I got the same results as I outlined in the answer with this line added/altered: CFLAGS='-O2 -DFORTDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes\"" -DOFFDIR="\"/usr/local/share/games/fortunes/off\"" -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DHAVE_REGEX_H -D_REGEX_RE_COMP -I../util' \
      LDFLAGS='-s' LIBS='

Comment: I don't know why you're having this problem, but you still haven't made clear what operating system you're compiling on.

Comment: Mac OSX (which /is/ BSD-based by the way).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  Unfortunately I have little experience with Mac OSX, and this is an operating system-specific problem, related to what libraries you need to link on Mac OSX (which will be different for other OS's).  I have two suggestions: first, you can re-tag your question with a Mac OSX specific tag so maybe some Mac OSX guru will see it, or second, you can rewrite the code to use the POSIX standard functions regcomp() and regex() instead of the BSD-only functions re_comp() and re_exec().

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a fork of the Mac port of fortune on github that's been adapted to compile as 64-bit.

https://github.com/tristanmorgan/Fortune-OSX/tree/sixty-four-bit